# Why is the Approve button disabled in GitHub "pull request review"?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

**Problem Background:**

So far I am the sole owner of a GitHub repo. I committed the code from my system to a branch called release (actually its a tag based on develop branch, if that matters). In GitHub, I created a pull request where **base branch is master** and **compare branch is release.**

But I am only **allowed to comment on review, not allowed to approve**. What may be the reason?

**Note:** There is no merge conflicts and while creating the pull request the green signal of merging possible was displayed.

[image]

***Here is how the master branch is protected by me:***

[image]

Comment: Hmmm...could this be a permissions issue?  Maybe you have to grant yourself certain rights to be able to see these options?

Comment: I suppose so. But not getting any clue. The GitHub docs and other resources have not pointed any such cases or any such permission. The only configurations option i could see was the setting options for the project. May be I need to dig more inside any not so intuitive tab.

Comment: hi, did you get a chance to review my answer?

Comment: @variable, reviewed.thanks for sharing the way to achieve this.

Comment: Please can you accept it as the answer - because the currently marked answer is incorrect.

Comment: @variable your answer is incorrect, this question about review, not about merging

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you were the one who has committed the pull request you cannot approve or request changes on this pull request. 
It's only available when someone else requested such action.

So your only option is to comment it.

Comment: This may not be the case as I have done it once in a different project. Also if we think logically, such use case should be permissible. Suppose, I am the only user and i don't want to commit to master branch directly, then committing the code from dev branch, raising pull request and then self approving it is ok. right?

Comment: @Dexter: you might think so. I might even agree. The folks at GitHub disagree. You'll have to take it up with them, since they are the ones controlling this.

Comment: @torek, thanks for you comment. could you please share a link for the same. i mean where can i get more info on this.

Comment: Accepting this as ans. I am convinced with the counter argument to my own previous argument- What is the point of your request if you yourself going to approve it. :). As I said-I was able to merge it once, perhaps it was because I had not made that branch protected..

Comment: I haven't fussed with the protected branch thing on GitHub, but I understand you can list yourself as an exception to the protection as well. I'm not sure what happens then.

Comment: Is there a documentation page anywhere that describes this limitation? (asking because sometimes you gotta send documentation to your auditors )

Comment: @skeggse, you should add this information into commit message if that's required.

Comment: I don't follow. I'm asking if there's a github documentation page that talks about this functionality in general.

Comment: Is there a setting that can change this? GitLab allows this option.

Comment: i wanted to weigh in that there is still a strong argument to be made for self-approval of owner code. i have a tightly controlled terraform repository and use atlantis to run terraform plans and applies - and comment on the pull request with the results of those plans/applies. as an owner, i know the rules, and should be able to open a pull request. atlantis should be able to comment on the pull request what the plan is, and i should be able to approve my own change if i like the plan. my only option without this feature is to not have iac transparency or not have a secure main branch.

Answer (score 12):

for me, the only option was disabling it.

disable **Require pull request reviews before merging** under settings > branches > the branch

*I am the only developer of my project, so maybe I cant review my own pull request. I make a pr, then merge it if tests pass....I know my answer doesn't answer the question exactly, but none of the fixes above worked....*

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: No, this is incorrect, this question about review, not about merging

Answer (score 6):

I am the only developer in my github profile. I am admin of the project. Yet I am not authorized to approve my own PR.
I do see an option to merge using admin Priviledges.
[image]

Comment: Where is this option?

Comment: You can have this option by disabling **Do not allow bypassing the above settings**. This is under branch protection rules. settings/branch_protection_rules.

Comment: @gwthm.in: I think @AG6HQ is asking where to see the thing in the screenshot. I have `Do not allow bypassing the above settings` disabled (which is the default) but I don't see the option in the screenshot.

Comment: If you have a PR - go to the bottom of your PR in `conversations` tab

Comment: @Aseem, github notes """these conflicts are too complex""" even though I have only one char of merge conflict lol.

Comment: I feel like this is the correct answer for the reasons a lot of people have mentioned, when I am the owner and only contributor, I don't need to review/comment to myself. For people with actions, I would think you can trigger the actions when the PR is pushed, then just bypass an merge.

Answer (score 4):

Go to settings->branches->main[edit] and uncheck this:
[image]

OR: If you do not see above image, you can uncheck this one:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like workaround until github adds BE validation :) But just open DevTools in your browser and remove `disabled` prop from the 'approve' radio button input. Works for me.
[image]

Comment: Today, I had to remove `checked="checked"` attribute from the `<input>` tag of the `Comment` radio button and add it to the `<input>` tag of the `Request changes` radio button. After clicking on `Submit review`, I see my comments as conversations to resolve. Thanks, @Tarás! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem as well.

The resolution for me, the only developer on the project, was to change the required approvals to 0.

This was part of the ruleset I have created to protect the main branch, not least protect it from me!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue today and managed to resolve it.

The problem occurs only when the Branch protection rule for the branch into which you are trying to put the code into has the following setting enabled: **Include administrators**

The definition of this setting is: *Enforces all configured restrictions above for administrators.*

Disable this setting and it will allow you as the sole owner to accept your own pull request.

Comment: This is incorrect, the same issue persists when "Include administrators" is disabled.

Comment: This answer is (partially) correct. I just checked, and you can bypass the "Branch protection rule" to merge your own PR if you are an administrator and the rule does not "Include administrators".

You'll see this message above the "Merge pull request" button: `As an administrator, you may still merge this pull request.` And once you click it, you need to confirm that you want to `Use your administrator privileges to merge this pull request.`

You can merge your own PR, but you still can't "Approve" or "Request changes", which is what the question asks about.

Answer (score 0):

Repository -> Settings -> Branches

Make sure your base branch must not be protected by the rule `Required approvals`

[image]

Comment: Hi Rahul, there was no merge conflicts for me as I had mentioned in the question. So as per your observation, now GitHub behavior has changed in this regard?

Comment: no, in case of Approve the behaviour is the same but I was able to merge the pull request by myself

Comment: You can merge only if base branch is not protected

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well, but I was able to resolve it by assigning the Pull request to myself.  This allowed me to review and merge my own pull request with the main branch.

Comment: are you sure you were able to review your own pull request? I checked right now, and with "Branch protection rules" all I can do is "Comment" on my own PR, but not "Approve" or "Request changes". Adding a comment won't allow me to merge the PR, so I don't think your solution works. Perhaps you managed to merge your own PR because your rules didn't "Include administrators".

Comment: I assigned the PR to myself , yet I couldn't approve it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and here's how I solved it:

1. The issue showed up when I went to: "my-repo" > "my-branch" > "pull requests" > select my pull request > "files changed" tab > "review changes" button on the right > "Approved" was disabled.
2. I solved it by going to "my-repo" > "my-branch" > "pull requests" > select my pull request > scroll down to the "Merge Pull Request" button and clicked it.

I didn't have to change any permissions.

Comment: This does not solve the problem "Approve is disabled". It only means you can merge.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to realize that I only needed this button located in the  Conversation tab.

[image: look here]