# Can I review my own pull request on GitHub?

Tags: github

I'd like to be able to review my own pull request on GitHub.

The motivation is to allow the last of N maintainers to merge the pull request once the other N-1 maintainers have approved. This way, anyone can push a commit and invalidate existing approvals, including mine.

Is there an option to enable this?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. Can you just require N-1 approvals instead of N?

Comment: That's not ideal because I'd like it to be possible for someone else to add a commit to the PR, thus requiring my approval even though I opened the PR.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the Approve button disabled in GitHub "pull request review"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50436095/why-is-the-approve-button-disabled-in-github-pull-request-review)