# How to restrict author to not review the code

Tags: github

I am the author of the code and I am also part of code owners group list(one of the member).
If any possible way to stop reviewing my code by myself. Because I am the author and supposed to not review the code.

Any rules can i implement to stop doing review

Comment: Although you can configure [auto-assignment](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/organizing-members-into-teams/managing-code-review-settings-for-your-team#about-auto-assignment) as well as [who can review](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/managing-repository-settings/managing-pull-request-reviews-in-your-repository) it does not seem documented to restrict yourself from reviews, although people are (somehow?) using this feature, so the answer might be buried here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50436095/3196753

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure that you have a branch protection rule defined for the branch the PR is going to be targeting.

Docs: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule

Once there, you will need to make sure you have at least the following checked off:

- Require a pull request before merging
- Require approvals (defaults to 1)
- Require review from Code Owners
- Do not allow bypassing the above settings

The last setting is the key for this to work correctly. This will require all users to adhere to the rule. Without it, admins and owners of the repo will be allowed to bypass the rule. Some organizations allow for this to prevent emergency fixes from getting blocked by "red tape".

Comment: Thanks for feedback.  I made all above settings. Ia m the one of member in code owners Team list. When i commit, the code am not supposed to review the code even am a team member of the list. Is there any way to stop review myself for my changes. Because the code is very critical need to review properly. I am not interested to add reviewer count as 2 0r 3 in setting....