# Why can't I approve my own PR in GitHub, even when I have disabled the setting for "Require approval from someone other than the last pusher"?

Tags: github

[GitHub says I can disable protections that prevent the last pusher from approving the PR](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-20-new-branch-protections-last-pusher-and-locked-branch/), but I am not able to even when I have that setting turned on. Is there some other setting I need to disable in my branch protections?

[image: approval is blocked]

[image: here are my settings]

I can still merge the pull request by bypassing the requirements (since I'm the administrator of the repository), but that's not what I want to do. I want to be able (and want other pushers to be able) to approve my own pull requests, as long as they are considered Code Owners (which I am, in this case).

I have tried enabling the setting and disabling it again. It does not seem to make a difference.

I created this PR before I even had branch protections turned on, and I turned off branch protections off altogether to confirm that the branch protection settings are indeed being updated.

I also tried requiring a PR but unchecking "require approvals" and leaving "require review from Code Owners" checked, and this did not work either.

Comment: If you can just merge without approval, what is the point of caring whether you can approve first?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50436095/why-is-the-approve-button-disabled-in-github-pull-request-review for some useful options, but I think you're worrying about nothing. What would you do if you could approve, add a comment telling yourself how clever you are?

Comment: I want other collaborators, who will not be admins (and, therefore, will not be able to merge without approval), to be able to approve their own PRs. 

GitHub has the setting for it, so I must not be alone in this desire.

Comment: If people can approve their own PRs why have PRs at all?

Comment: Thanks for the point to that other thread, but unfortunately that question was asked at a time before GitHub implemented the setting I am asking about, so none of the answers are relevant to the context of my question, which is specifically about this new setting.

If I should bring up my question on that thread, please let me know. I assumed it was bad practice to ask my own question on someone else's thread, especially one that is over 4 years old.

Comment: @matt we do something similar with our integration `next` branch; we require a PR but allow people to approve their own. The branch is auto-built and deployed to a testing environment and the benefit (compared to allowing pushing) is that we can force a merge commit with the PR and can see in the history exactly when certain commits landed on the branch, which helps with troubleshooting when something breaks. (In theory admins could decipher the push logs and determine the same, but letting everyone see it right in the branch history is easier.)

Comment: @matt cont... The second major advantage of having the PR is that we can have gated checkins. So a developer pushes their branch, creates a PR into `next`, approves it, turns on auto-complete, and once all the gates pass it completes automatically. A third advantage, is if a developer wants feedback, they can solicit it from other devs, instead of completing it on their own. (Since we're already used to the PR code review process.)

Comment: My experience (described in my previous comments) with allowing devs to approve and complete their own PRs is with AzDO, not GH, so I'm not certain if it's even possible in GH. Based on your screenshots my interpretation is that the setting for preventing the last pusher from approving, is a separate rule from the across the board setting of: "you can't approve your own PR". In other words, if a different person pushed than the creator of the PR, with that setting on a third person would be required to approve, but turning that setting off doesn't suddenly enable the creator to approve.

Comment: The screenshot makes it look like you can require a PR but uncheck "require approvals" and leave checked "require review from Code Owners". Would that work?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately I did try this as well, and it did not work. I still was not able to approve the PR because I was the last pusher. I'll update the post to clarify that I tried this.

Comment: @Braden.Biz so even with "Require approvals" and "Require approval from someone other than the last pusher" *both* unchecked, you still couldn't complete?

Comment: I just realized someone posted that exact thing as an answer- I feel like that should work.

Comment: Ah... I see what you're saying, now. My bad! I think you may be right about the fact that GitHub doesn't allow you to approve your own PR, ever. 

My goal here is not to get my PR through, I've already been able to do that.

My goal was to allow approvals of my own PRs, and to make approvals required. Sounds like it's just not possible. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Seems similar to this issue: [Allow a code owners' PRs to be approved by non-owners #9636](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/9636)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As TTT pointed out,

GitHub does not allow one to approve their own PRs that they created, ever.

The setting for "*Require approval from someone other than the last pusher*" is most likely an additional check on top of that, for if someone pushed to a PR that they did not create/own.

So it seems there is no way to enable the functionality that I wanted.

Comment: Just to add, another user would have to be a contributor in order to push to your branch. So once you add contributors, you can reenable this option.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution works for me; I am the only one working in the repository, so it may not be appropriate for other situations.

On the settings page, select "Branches". Select "Edit" in the Branch Protection Rule.
Make sure that these two checkboxes are unchecked:

1. Require approvals
   When enabled, pull requests targeting a matching branch require a number of approvals and no changes requested before they can be merged.
2. Require approval from someone other than the last pusher
   Require review approval from someone other than the last pusher to the pull request branch.

Comment: This allows me to get the PR through, yes, but it was not my goal. 

I wanted to be able to approve my own PRs, but it seems GitHub does not allow it.

Thanks for the help!